# How to solve concurrentmodification exception on mapactivity?

Tags: android, mapactivity

I am developing an application that is using map activity and itemized Overlay class for tracking and displaying the markers on the map. But I am getting some times concurrent modification exception.

Comment: could you add a sample code so that we can look into it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding/removing items from the Overlay from any other thread other than the UI thread, you will come across this exception.

Comment: @Ganesh if Reno's post solved your issue, kindly tag it as the answer ;-)